# Compare preceding two rows with current and next row using Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a data like as shown below

```
rno id day  val
0   1   1   7
1   1   2   5
2   1   3   10
3   1   4   10
4   1   5   11
5   1   6   11
6   1   7   14
7   1   8   14
20  2   1   5
21  2   2   7
22  2   3   8
23  2   4   8
24  2   5   9
25  2   6   9
26  2   7   13
27  2   8   13
28  2   9   15
29  2   10  15
```

I would like to create a new column as `fake_flag` and fill in values as `fake_val` based on below two rules

**rule 1** - for each val (`n`), check whether the preceding two rows (`n-1`,`n-2`) are constant or decreasing (ex: 7,5 or 5,5 is valid whereas 5,7 is not valid because it is increasing and not constant as well) and get the max value as  output. if it's 7,5, the output will be 7. if it's 5,5 then the output will be 5

**rule 2** - check whether the current value (`n`) and next value (`n+1`) is more than max of rule 1 output by 3 or more points (>=3). Ex: if rule 1 output was 5, then we expect to see atleast 8 (`n`),8(`n+1`). It could be 9,9 or 10,10

I expect my output data to look like as shown below

```
rno id day  val fake_flag
0   1   1   7     
1   1   2   5     
2   1   3   10    fake_val  # >= 3 from max of preceding 2 rows and `n` and `n+1` is same 
3   1   4   10     
4   1   5   11
5   1   6   11
6   1   7   14    fake_val  # >= 3 from max of preceding 2 rows and `n` and `n+1` is same 
7   1   8   14
20  2   1   5
21  2   2   7
22  2   3   8
23  2   4   8
24  2   5   9
25  2   6   9
26  2   7   13    fake_val    # >= 3 from max of preceding 2 rows and `n` and `n+1` is same 
27  2   8   13
28  2   9   15
29  2   10  15
```

Comment: Sorry, trying to understand this - what happens when rule #1 is broken? Like if it was  7, 9 as the previous vals ? Or are you saying that would never happen

Comment: Both rule 1 and rule 2 should satisfy to qualify a record as `fake_val`. If rule 1 is broken, then you will not have `fake_val`. Did it help? Only when both rule 1 and rule 2 are satisifed, you fill the column with `fake_val` value. else ignore it

Comment: If you see my example screenshot, for `id=2`, check the first two rows. It is like what you said

Comment: and you said for rule 2 it could 8, 8, 9,9 or 10,10 but it could also be >10 correct?

Comment: Yes,it can be greater than 10 as well

Comment: Both the answers below were helpful and works fine. I can only choose one answer and have chosen @Mikhail as it was a bit straight forward and simple for beginner like me to understand. Nonetheless both the answers works fine and were very helpful. I thank both Mark and WIT for their help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT rno, id, day, val, 
  IF(IFNULL(val_prev2 > val_prev1, FALSE)                   -- rule 1
    OR ( 
      (val - GREATEST(val_prev2, val_prev1) >= 3)           -- rule 2 for val(n)
      AND (val_next - GREATEST(val_prev2, val_prev1) >= 3)  -- rule 2 for val(n+1)
    ), 
    'fake_val', ''
  ) AS fake_flag
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    LAG(val) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY day) val_prev1,
    LAG(val, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY day) val_prev2,
    LEAD(val) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY day) val_next
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row rno id  day val fake_flag    
1   0   1   1   7        
2   1   1   2   5        
3   2   1   3   10  fake_val     
4   3   1   4   10       
5   4   1   5   11       
6   5   1   6   11       
7   6   1   7   14  fake_val     
8   7   1   8   14       
9   20  2   1   5        
10  21  2   2   7        
11  22  2   3   8        
12  23  2   4   8        
13  24  2   5   9        
14  25  2   6   9        
15  26  2   7   13  fake_val     
16  27  2   8   13       
17  28  2   9   15       
18  29  2   10  15
```

Answer (score 3):

This should accomplish what you want. I tested it out with dummy data, but if I didn't understand some part let me know and I can amend.

```
Select *
, CASE WHEN 
  -- Rule 1
  (LAG(val, 1) over w <= LAG(val, 2) over w)  AND 
  (val = LEAD(val, 1) over w) AND -- n = n + 1, part of rule 2
   -- Can assume row n-2 is the max because it will either be the same as row n-1 or greater than row n-1 for rule 1 to be satisfied
  (LAG(val, 2) over w <= val + 3) -- Only have to check current row val because for first part of rule 2 to be satisfied val for row n must equal val for row n + 1
  THEN 'fake_val' -- I would just have a 1 representing it is true and then 0 if not, but up to you 
  ELSE null 
  END as fake_flag
from Dataset.Table_name
WINDOW w as (ORDER BY rno ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
```